# How to Zoom a Drawn Image in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey everyone, a new guy here in C#.Net.

What I need is to zoom an image drawn using gdi+ to pictureBox.

I searched but couldn't find a nice answer, **all I found was for existing files**.
Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks for the answers.

My best Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Transforms and Matrix objects as [described here](http://en.csharp-online.net/GDIplus_Graphics_Transformation%E2%80%94Matrix_Class_and_Transformation).
The example of scaling is given as

```
private void Scale_Click(object sender,
  System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Create Graphics object
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.Clear(this.BackColor);
    // Draw a filled rectangle with
    // width 20 and height 30
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue,
        20, 20, 20, 30);
    // Create Matrix object
    Matrix X = new Matrix();
    // Apply 3X scaling
    X.Scale(3, 4, MatrixOrder.Append);
    // Apply transformation on the form
    g.Transform = X;
    // Draw a filled rectangle with
    // width 20 and height 30
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue,
        20, 20, 20, 30);
    // Dispose of object
    g.Dispose();
}
```